# how to print out the properties of log4j (1.2.17)

Tags: log4j

Now I want to print out the properties of log4j at runtime,

I only found how to set properties for log4j at runtime, but didn't

see any solution to get the properties, does anyone know how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add log4j.debug to the JVM system variables.

```
java -Dlog4j.debug -cp <classname>
```

Comment: this way only can show properties on console, doesn't it? If I want to write the property info to a file, how can i do ?

Comment: if you are using Linux direct the outputs to a file as below using arrow ">".
java -Dlog4j.debug -cp <classname> > output.txt

Comment: I tried ur solution, it does work, thank u very much ^^